# Stop processing when the number of consecutive list elements have a unique value

Tags: python

I have a long record of data in a list format which I want to separate that record according to a certain condition. I want to get the sum of the list elements so the sum order will stop when consecutive 3 or more elements are equal to 0, then the sum order restarts again from where it stopped.

for ex: part of the list is [8, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0]

the output should be a new list of [14, 8, 6] where: output1: 8 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 2 = 14, output2: 6 + 2 = 8,
and output3: 6

I write so far something like below but I have two problems:
1- list index out of range,
2- the fake list extension with three 0 elements at the end of the list

```
# note: i add three fake 0 at the end of the list to get the correct output
arr = [8, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0]
result = []
cum = 0        
for i in range(0, len(arr)):
   el, el1, el2 = arr[i], arr[i+1], arr[i+2]
   if el != 0:
       cum = cum + el
   if el == 0 and el1 == 0 and el2 == 0: 
       if cum != 0:
          result.append(cum)
          cum = 0
```

Comment: Any chance the `sum` is misspelled?

Comment: @ CrazyChucky, yes I intend to avoid the word (sum) because it is used as a built-in function. I got your point, sorry i never think about the other word that i used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve both your problems:

```
arr = [8, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0]
    result = []
    cum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(arr) - 2):
        el, el1, el2 = arr[i], arr[i + 1], arr[i + 2]
        if el != 0:
            cum = cum + el
        if el == 0 and el1 == 0 and el2 == 0:
            if cum != 0:
                result.append(cum)
                cum = 0
        elif i == len(arr) - 3:
            cum = el + el1 + el2
            result.append(cum)
            break

    print(result)
```

The 'elif i == len(arr) - 3:' condition makes sure that your loop breaks when you have reached last 3 elements. Additionally it will execute only when at least 1 element is non-zero from last three.

Comment: Could you help please to add the following:
 count the number of elements for each splitting

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Could you mention the expected count in your example above?

Comment: can you check this, please (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67737821/counting-non-zero-elements-when-the-number-of-consecutive-list-elements-have-a-u)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```py
a = [8, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0]
total_list = []
i = 0
sum = 0
for ind, ele in enumerate(a):
  if ind < (len(a) - 2):
    sum += ele
    if (a[ind] == 0) and (a[ind+1] == 0) and (a[ind+2] == 0):
      if sum != 0:
        total_list.append(sum)
        sum = 0
  else:
    sum += ele
    if sum != 0:
      total_list.append(sum)
      sum = 0

print(total_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [8, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0]
result = []
cum = 0        
for i in range(0, len(arr)-2):
   el, el1, el2 = arr[i], arr[i+1], arr[i+2]
   if el != 0:
       cum = cum + el
   if el == 0 and el1 == 0 and el2 == 0: 
       if cum != 0:
          result.append(cum)
          cum = 0
print(result)
```

Comment: thanks, your code solve my problem 1 and but problem 2 is still there

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [8, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0]
result = []
cum = 0
zeros = 0
for i in range(0, len(arr)):
   el = arr[i]
   if el != 0:
       cum = cum + el
       zeros = 0
   if el == 0:
        zeros += 1
        if cum != 0 and zeros == 3:
            result.append(cum)
            cum = 0
```

you can use a variable to track the number of 0 you meet in your array, this doesn't remove the problem of "appending" three 0s at the end of array, which could programmatically be done by adding at the beginning arr.extend([0,0,0])

Comment: good point of the new variable (zeros) to track the 0 numbers, thanks