# Counting and summing list elements, in sections separated by three or more zeros

Tags: python

I have a list of integers which I want to separate according to a certain condition. I want to get the sum and the count of the list elements, stopping when three or more consecutive elements are equal to 0; then the sum and count orders restart again from where they stopped.

For example, part of the list is:

```
[8, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0]
```

The process would be:

```
8, 2, 1, 1, 2 -> sum: 14, length: 5
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
6, 0, 2       -> sum: 8, length: 3
0, 0, 0
8, 0, 0, 2    -> sum: 10, length: 4
0, 0, 0
6, 0, 0       -> sum: 6, length: 3
```

So the output I want is:

```
[[14, 5], [8, 3], [10, 4], [6, 3]]
```

What I've written so far computes the sum okay, but my problem is that zeros within sections aren't counted in the lengths.

Current (incorrect) output:

```
[[14, 5], [8, 2], [10, 2], [6, 2]]
```

Code:

```
arr = [8, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0]
result = []
summed, count = 0, 0
for i in range(0, len(arr) - 2):
    el, el1, el2 = arr[i], arr[i + 1], arr[i + 2]
    if el != 0:
        summed = summed + el
        count = count + 1
    if el == 0 and el1 == 0 and el2 == 0:
        if summed != 0:
            result.append([summed, count])
            summed = 0
            count = 0
    elif i == len(arr) - 3:
        summed = el + el1 + el2
        count = count + 1
        result.append([summed, count])
        break

print(result)
```

Comment: Hi, shouldn't the answer be [[14,5], [8,5], [10,6], [6,5]] ?

Comment: @ bot-coder101 no, I want the count to stop when the sum stop also.

Comment: what the count exactly means? Is it counting of zeros or only numbers?

Comment: While I don't think you actually need to be doing such a thing, the way you loop through three elements at a time is a reimplementation of [windowed](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.windowed) from [More Itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/), which is a handy library to know about. Your current loop code could be written as `for el1, el2, el3 in windowed(arr, 3):`. If you're manually using list indexes in a Python for loop, there's [almost always](https://treyhunner.com/2016/04/how-to-loop-with-indexes-in-python/) a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: @CrazyChucky: got it, thanks for the advice. the function (enumerate) is one of the very useful ones for iteratating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```py
a = [8, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0,0]
total_list = []
i = 0
sum_int = 0
count_int = 0
for ind, ele in enumerate(a):
  if ind < (len(a) - 2):
    sum_int += ele
    if sum_int != 0:
      count_int += 1
    if (a[ind] == 0) and (a[ind+1] == 0) and (a[ind+2] == 0):
      if sum_int != 0:
        count_int -= 1
        total_list.append([sum_int, count_int])
        sum_int = 0
        count_int = 0
  else:
    sum_int += ele
    count_int += 1
    if sum_int != 0:
      total_list.append([sum_int, count_int+1])
      sum_int = 0
      count_int = 0

print(total_list)
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to shadow builtin functions (like `sum`) with variable names.

Comment: @CrazyChucky: indeed, i change sum with a variable called cum. thanks for the advice

Comment: @MostafaGomaa I'd recommend picking something else, at least for a polite English-speaking setting.

Comment: @CrazyChucky: sorry, you are right. I didn't think that much about the other word that I used. I will change it

Comment: That triple conditional could be simplified to `if a[ind : ind+3] == [0, 0, 0]:`. And more generally, it's really better to explain why and how code works (either in comments or outside the code) than to simply say "Here it is." This code works, but it's not immediately apparent *why* without studying it.

Answer (score 5):

It is quite hard to understand what your code does. Working with Strings seems more straightforward and readable, your output can be achieved in just two lines (thanks to @CrazyChucky for the improvement):

```
import re 

arr = [8, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0]
# Convert to String by joining integers, and split into substrings, the separator being three zeros or more
strings = re.split(r'0{3,}', ''.join(str(i) for i in arr))
# Sums and counts using list comprehensions
output = [[sum(int(x) for x in substring), len(substring)] for substring in strings]
```

Output:

```
>>>output
>>>[[14, 5], [8, 3], [10, 4], [6, 3]]
```

Remember that readability is always the most important factor in any code. One should read your code for the first time and understand how it works.

If the full list contains numbers with more than one digit, you can do the following:

```
# Convert to String by joining integers, seperating them by a commade, and split into substrings, the separator being three zeros or more
strings = re.split(r',?(?:0,){3,}', ','.join(str(i) for i in arr))
# Make a list of numbers from those strings
num_lists = [string.split(',') for string in strings]
# # Sums and counts using list comprehensions
output = [[sum(int(x) for x in num_list), len(num_list)] for num_list in num_lists]
```

Comment: Hi Paul Lemarchand, thanks for your proposal, but I still need the data in integers since more processing will be done after the split

Comment: @MostafaGomaa The output only contains integers. I am not sure what you mean by 'data'. I am only using strings temporarely to find the output.

Comment: I think this would give incorrect output if the list *starts* with one or two zeroes, since they should be included in count. What if you used `re.split` instead of `str.split`, so that you actually split on three *or more* zeroes? Then you wouldn't need the `re.sub` step either.

Comment: So, `strings = re.split(r'0{3,}', ''.join(str(i) for i in arr))`. Then it's only two lines! Clever thought to use `re` in the first place, it hadn't even occurred to me.

Comment: @CrazyChucky I have updated my code to include your comment. The more I think about it, the more I like the way you did it. It's readable and concise. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Paul Lemarchand: you are right. I admit that not all my coding is that readable and I still need to improve. Thanks anyway

Comment: Very neat idea, I like it. But what if the full list contains numbers with more than one digit?

Comment: @Arne That wouldn't work, because what makes this solution is that each char corresponds to a different integer. This is specific to this problem.

Comment: Yes, that's my point. OP didn't state that their full list were this simple.

Comment: @Arne That's a good catch. However, it could be worked around by using a delimiter other than `''`. Join the list on `','`, for instance, then just change your regex to `r'(?:0,){3,}'` and split it on `','`. (@PaulLemarchand perhaps you should add this as well?)

Comment: @CrazyChucky I have added your recommendation, I had to find workarounds for the sums and counts but nothing complicated. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of wrangling `re.findall()`, I'd recommend splitting on `,`. You already know that's your delimiter, since you joined it yourself. If you add a line assigning `num_lists = [string.split(',') for string in strings]`, then you can generate the output the same way you were already doing: `output = [[sum(int(x) for x in num_list), len(num_list)] for num_list in num_lists`.

Comment: @CrazyChucky do you have a solution for the regex to match `0,0,0,0,0` and not `0,0,0,0,0,`? It would be great to not have those additionnal commas at the end of substrings because it makes an empty string at the end of lists which cannot be converted to integer.

Comment: @PaulLemarchand If I understand you correctly, I think you might have written that backwards. It would indeed be a good idea if the regular expression which defines the multiple-zeros delimiter gobbled up the comma *before* the zeros, like `,0,0,0,`, so it doesn't remain at the end of the previous run of nonzeros. r',?(?:0,){3,}' should take care of that.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Sorry for the confusion, you are right. I updated my post, all good now. Thanks a lot, you are of great help.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not so much to suggest a way I'd recommend doing it, as to highlight how clever [Paul Lemarchand's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67738239/12975140) of using a regular expression is. Without Python's `re` module doing the heavy lifting for you, you have to either look ahead to see how many zeros are coming (as in [Prakash Dahal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67738830/12975140)), or keep track of how many zeros you've seen as you go. I think this implementation of the latter is about the simplest and shortest way you could solve this problem "from scratch":

```
input_list = [8, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0,
              0, 6, 0, 0]

output_list = []
current_run = []
pending_zeros = 0

for num in input_list:
    # If the number is 0, increment the number of "pending" zeros. (We
    # don't know yet if they're part of a separating chunk or not.)
    if num == 0:
        pending_zeros += 1

    # If this is the first nonzero after three or more zeros, process
    # the existing run and start over from the current number.
    elif pending_zeros >= 3:
        output_list.append((sum(current_run), len(current_run)))
        current_run = [num]
        pending_zeros = 0

    # Otherwise, the pending zeros (if any) should be included in the
    # current run. Add them, and then the current number.
    else:
        current_run += [0] * pending_zeros
        current_run.append(num)
        pending_zeros = 0

# Once we're done looping, there will still be a run of numbers in the
# buffer (assuming the list had any nonzeros at all). It may have
# pending zeros at the end, too. Include the zeros if there are 2 or
# fewer, then process.
if current_run:
    if pending_zeros <= 2:
        current_run += [0] * pending_zeros
    output_list.append((sum(current_run), len(current_run)))

print(output_list)
```

```
[(14, 5), (8, 3), (10, 4), (6, 3)]
```

One note: I made each entry in the list a tuple rather than a list. Tuples and lists have a [lot of overlap](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/), and in this case either would probably work perfectly well... but a tuple is a more idiomatic choice for an immutable data structure that will always be the same length, in which each position refers to something different. (In other words, it's not a list of equivalent items, but rather a well-defined combination of `(sum, length)`.)